# Django permission to create a folder when being served by Apache2

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am serving a Django site using Apache2 and mod_wgsi on a Debian 8 machine.

I have correctly set the permissions to access the database and static file directories and the directory my_site/media.

However, the site needs to create a directory in my_site/media (i.e. my_site/media/another_directory) and I can't seem to give apache2 permission to do this.

The permission for media are:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 scamp www-data   4096 Jan 10 03:09 media
```

The Django error I get is

```
Exception Type: PermissionError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'media/new_folder'
```

This is my django.conf:

```
Alias /robots.txt /home/scamp/trcalc_django/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/scamp/trcalc_django/static/favicon.ico
Alias /media/ /home/scamp/trcalc_django/media/
Alias /static /home/scamp/trcalc_django/static
<Directory /home/scamp/trcalc_django/static>
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /home/scamp/trcalc_django/media>
Require all granted
</Directory>
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/scamp/trcalc_django/wsgi.py
<Directory /home/scamp/trcalc_django>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

Is there something else I need to put in the apache conf? or some other permissions that need to be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a relative path for files. You must calculate an absolute path. This is because the current working directory of the process isn't going to be where your project is. See mod_wsgi documentation for more details.

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#application-working-directory
- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/application-issues.html#access-rights-of-apache-user

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you referring to `<Files wsgi.py>`?

Comment: No. The exception gives a partial path of ``media/new_folder``. This suggests you are using relative paths in your Django setting file. So I am talking about in your Python code.